# Add Running Total Net Column

Tags: crystal-reports

My report has a credit and debit column. I would like to add a Net column next to it to keep a running total. How would I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Is this a Crosstab?

Comment: no. my report just has the debit and credit columns. I just gave the example above to better explain what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your report? You can censor out any sensitive information, but it's important to see what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula like this:

```
Dr_cr := if isnull({Credit}) then {Debit} else -{Credit}
```

Apply a running total on that formula. (In Field Explorer, right-click *Running Total Fields* and click *New*.)

In the *Create Running Total Field* dialog box, name the running total object in the *Running Total Name* field. Then select the formula fields to summarize.